# Am I able to sum records together by type

Tags: sql

Lets say my data looks like this

```
Animal  Number
dog     3
dog     5
dog     1
cat     2
cat     5
horse   2
horse   4
```

Lets lets say I want to combine dog and cat together with this data set but also show the original individual animals. I know I can just use sum to add the individual animals, but how do I combine cat & dog together.

```
Animal  Number
dog     9
cat     7
horse   6
cat+dog 16
```

Answer (score 1):

The first idea that comes to my mind is a `union`.

```sql
select Animal, sum(Number) as Number
from my_table
group by Animal

union all

select 'cat+dog' as Animal, sum(Number) as Number
from my_table
where Animal in ('cat', 'dog')
group by Animal
;
```

Comment: Are you missing a `group by`?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot the `group by`, thanks @Stu.

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct
    coalesce(
        case when Animal in ('cat', 'dog') then 'cat+dog' else Animal end,
        Animal) as Category,
    sum(Number) as "Number"
from T
group by grouping sets (
    (Animal),
    (case when Animal in ('cat', 'dog') then 'cat+dog' else Animal end)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate as normal and combine a separate aggregation using Union. Note your results have arbitrary ordering.

```
select animal, Sum(number) Number
from t
group by animal

union all

select 'cat+dog', sum(Number)
from t
where Animal in ('cat', 'dog');
```